# Is the integral $\iint _ {D}f(x,y)dA$ necessarily defined?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration, multiple-integral

> Let $D$ be a bounded, open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $f: D ⟶ \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded, continuous function. Then is the integral $\iint _ {D}f(x,y)dA$  necessarily defined?

I tried to approach this problem by studying the behavior of the bounds. My intuition says that since $D$ is a bounded, continuous function the limits exist and hence the integral is defined. However, I'm not sure how to rigorously prove this.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a definition of integrability in $2$ dimensions? I think it suffices to imitate the proof that continuous functions are integrable in $1$ dimension.

Comment: I'm 95% certain that the boundary of a bounded open set in $\mathbb\{R}^2$ is going to be a measure 0 set.   If that's true, you can just look an extension of $f$ to the closure, get integral for free,  then subtract the boundary which is 0.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins do you mean the proof of Reimann integrals?

Comment: Is this a Riemann or Lebesgue integral? In the former case there's a geometric obstruction to defining the integral since the measure of $\partial D$ is not necessarily zero (and thus $D$ is not Jordan measurable). In the latter case, you can always approximate by step functions in a nice way.

Comment: @Jose27 this is a Lebesgue integral - do you have any resources I can reference for the approximation?

Comment: Any book on measure theory should have this; it's the way you define the integral as the limit of integrals of step functions.

Comment: If this is a Lebesgue integral why is there a Riemann integration tag? Anyway a continuous function is Borel (and hence Lebesgue) measurable. Next, $D$ is an open hence (Borel and Lebesgue) measurable, so there's no regularity issues; now integrability is only a matter of finiteness; thisbis obvious since you have a bounded function on a bounded (hence finite Lebesgue measure) set. So indeed $\int_D f\, dA$ is defined.